# How to drop a table which starts with an apostrophe

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In a bit of a pickle, I have somehow managed to get a typo applied to a column name and for this database, I have only CLI access, which is not allowing me to escape out the single apostrophe in the column name to apply a `DROP COLUMN` statement to it:

`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN 'my_typod_column;`

I have tried wrapping the column in double quotes, doubling up the single quote and using a backslash, to no avail.

My next attempt to solve it will be to create a temporary table from this one, cherry-picking all but this column, then replacing the current table with it, but is less desirable. Hoping for a solution to escape the single quote on CLI instead.

**Environment info**

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
>
> bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Did backticks work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried backticks?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN `'my_typod_column`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping your column name in backticks

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN `'my_typod_column`;
```

:)